Vuetify V-calendar don't show some events and replaces them with (1 more) label even there isn't other events in that day
I'm displaying a whole year using different v-calendars, but for some reason in some months the event is not displayed right.

As you can see, the events are not displayed even though the data structure is the same. And it happens in different months across diferent datasets.
Here is the template for the v-calendars.
                        <v-col
                          v-for="(month, index) in monthList" :key="month.name + '-' + index" 
                          cols="12" sm="6" md="4" class="ma-0 pa-0 px-2 mb-3"
                        >
                          <v-card color="white" class="ma-0 pa-0" style="border-radius: 16px;">
                            <v-row class="ma-0 pa-0 pa-2 mb-2 monthTitle" justify="center">
                              {{ month.name + ' de ' + currentYear }}
                            </v-row>
                            <v-row class="ma-0 pa-0 mb-20">
                              <v-col cols="12" class="ma-0 pa-0 px-1 pb-2">
                                <v-calendar
                                  :value="currentYear + '-' + month.monthNum + '-01'"
                                  :events="getEventsForMonth(month.name)"
                                  @click:event="show"
                                  width="100%" elevation="0"
                                  :show-month-on-first="false"
                                  :weekday-format="weekDayFormat"
                                  class="pa-0 ma-0 single tarjeta"
                                  prev-icon="" next-icon="" 
                                  :locale="$i18n.locale"
                                  no-title style="border-radius:16px;" color="white"
                                >
                                </v-calendar>
                              </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                          </v-card>
                        </v-col>

Here is how i get the events:
getEventsForMonth(monthName) {
          let monthData = this.selected[monthName];
          let events = [];
          if (!monthData) {
            return [];
          }
          monthData.forEach(eventData => {
            const allDay = true;

            const start = eventData.sd;
            const end = eventData.ed;

            events.push({
              name: 'Event ' + eventData._id,
              _id: eventData._id,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              color: this.getColor(eventData._id), 
              timed: !allDay, 
            });
          });

          return events;
        },

And this is the data provided for the months displayed in the image:
"Enero": [
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-01",
                "ed": "2024-01-01"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-06",
                "ed": "2024-01-07"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-10",
                "ed": "2024-01-14"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-18",
                "ed": "2024-01-24"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-27",
                "ed": "2024-01-30"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-01-31",
                "ed": "2024-01-31"
            }
        ],
"Marzo": [
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-01",
                "ed": "2024-03-02"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-03",
                "ed": "2024-03-03"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-05",
                "ed": "2024-03-06"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-11",
                "ed": "2024-03-13"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-14",
                "ed": "2024-03-14"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-22",
                "ed": "2024-03-25"
            },
            {
                "_id": ,
                "sd": "2024-03-27",
                "ed": "2024-03-28"
            }
        ],

Versions of the project:
"vue": "^2.6.14",
"vuetify": "^2.6.1",

I looked everywhere and I haven't found any other person having this issue. I'm looking maybe for a way to force the display of the event in the calendar but I've found nothing.

Not sure if this can be answered without debugging. Consider providing a snippet or a link where the problem can be examined, or add a bounty.
